# Waad Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have been trying to explore the offerings with WAAD and for this I have been trying to use ADAL and windows Azure to authenticate a console application.

Most of the time the call to AcquireToken just hangs and doesn't comes back. Is there a way I can trace out what is wrong in below code.

```
private const string Tenant = "ADOnline.onmicrosoft.com";
private const string Clientid = "dc1720ad....";
private static readonly Uri ReturnUri = new Uri("http://waadconsole");
private const string Resource = "https://graph.windows.net";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var _context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" +Tenant);
    var result = _context.AcquireToken(Resource, Clientid, ReturnUri, promptBehavior:PromptBehavior.Always);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Got Token!");
}
```

Thanks,
Shiju Samuel

Comment: What do you mean by hang? Do you see the user authentication page? What version of ADAL are you using? You can turn on ADAL traces using the instructions here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#logs

Comment: I am on windows 10 build 10041 with ADAL 2.14.0.0. The display of authentication page is not very consistent although I have kept promptBehavior:PromptBehavior.Always. Whenever that happens, the control just stuck at _context.acquiretoken call forever and I have to force kill the session.

Comment: Have you ever had a similar problem on Windows 8? Did you get a chance to get ADAL traces while getting a repro?